# Can someone explain amor fati to me?

Tags: nietzsche, love

Can someone explain amor fati to me?

Does it just mean love who you presently are? That seems a bit bourgeois to me. Does it mean that there's no explanation for why anything happens? Again, that seems a bit wrong, to say it's all senseless.

Is it a state of mind and/or a way of acting, and if so how is it cultivated etc.?

Comment: *Don’t demand that things happen as you wish, but wish that they happen as they do happen, and you will go on well* — Epictetus

Comment: See [Amor fati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amor_fati).

Comment: quite helpful in a way "want to learn more and more to see as beautiful what is necessary in things; then I shall be one of those who makes things beautiful." @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks